# Raspberry Pi + Arduino + Python - Value Error: Need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am working on getting an integration working between a hacked `MindFlex EEG` reader to `Arduino Uno` to `Raspberry Pi` working. I've followed the instructions to the letter from the source, which is [here](http://winkleink.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/angry-brain-cambridge-jam-raspberry-pi.html). Here is the code:

```
from pygame import *
import random
import time
import serial

#   set up the serial port
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

# Clear the serial input buffer

ser.flushInput()

# variables for colours
black = [ 0, 0, 0]
white = [255,255,255]
red = [255, 0, 0]
blue = [0,0,255]
darkBlue = [0,0,128]
pink = [255,200,255]
green = [0,255,0]
orange = [255,102,0]
brown = [153,102,0]
yellow = [255,255,0]
purple = [128,0,128]

# gap in wall
gap  = 200

# width and height of screen
width = 1000
height = 600
count_gap = int(height/gap)

# 0 = hard, 1 = easier, 2 is easiest
difficulty = 2

# class to create sprites and render them
class Sprite:
def __init__(self,xpos,ypos,filename):
    self.x = xpos
    self.y = ypos
    self.bitmap = image.load(filename)
def render(self):
    screen.blit(self.bitmap,(self.x,self.y))

# screen size
size=[width,height]
# initialise pygame
init()

# create the screen (window)
screen = display.set_mode(size)

# Caption to go at the top of the window
display.set_caption("Flappy EEG 2")

# set the music, its volume and start to play. -1 means infinite loop
mixer.music.load("Pinky_and_the_Brain.ogg")
mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
mixer.music.play(-1)

# create sound for crash
crasheffect = mixer.Sound("ouch.ogg")


# fill the screen with blue, update the screen
# not really required but I like it
screen.fill(blue)
display.update()
#time.sleep(1)

# create the sprites for the brain, columns and the background image

playerbrain = Sprite(20,200,"brain_75.png")
column1 = Sprite(1200,100,"column1.png")
column2 = Sprite(1200,100,"column2.png")
background = Sprite(0,0,"background.png")

# set fonts for different purposes
scorefont = font.Font(None,60)
datafont = font.Font(None,20)
overfont = font.Font(None,100)

# set default values for some variables
score = 0
maxscore = 0
quit = 0
gameover = 0

# master loop for the program. If quit == 0 then exit program
while quit == 0:
# flush the serial port of all data to begin fresh
ser.flushInput()

gameover = 0

# set the height of top column
column1.y = (random.randrange(0,(count_gap))*gap)-800

# set the height of the bottom column
column2.y = column1.y + 800 + gap

# start of loop (using while) to move the columns

# start off screen to the right
x = width +50

# x>-100 means still valid (yes there is a minus in there)
# gameover when collision
# quit selected. either pressed q or click x on window
while x >-100 and gameover == 0 and quit == 0:

# increment the score and if higher than maxscore make maxscore = score
    score = score + 1
    if score > maxscore:
        maxscore = score

# update columns location and set x positions
    x = x - 50
    column1.x = x
    column2.x =x

    data = ser.readline()
# print data

    signal,att,med,delta,theta,lalpha,halpha,lbeta,hbeta,lgamma,hgamma
= data.split(",")
    print "signal: " + signal
    print "attention: " + att
    print "data: " + data
    intatt = int(att)
    if intatt > 90:
        intatt = 90
    brainpos = intatt * 6
# set brain location based att (attention)

# is intatt near the gap above
    if brainpos < column1.y +800 and brainpos > column1.y + 800 -
(difficulty * 10):
        playerbrain.y = column1.y +800 +70
        print "brain near top and moved down!"
# is intatt near gap bottom
    elif brainpos > column2.y-75 and brainpos < column2.y +
(difficulty * 10):
        playerbrain.y = column1.y +800 +70
        print "brain near bottom and moved up!"

    else:
        playerbrain.y = brainpos
        print "brain where is should be"


# print playerbrain.y
    background.render()
    playerbrain.render()
    column1.render()
    column2.render()

# display some information on screen
    screen.blit(scorefont.render("Score: "+ str(score),1,white), (100, 5))
    screen.blit(scorefont.render("High Score: "+
str(maxscore),1,white), (400, 5))

    screen.blit(datafont.render("signal: "+ signal,1,white), (5, 570))
    screen.blit(datafont.render("attention: "+ att,1,white), (150, 570))

    screen.blit(datafont.render("playerbrain.y: "+
str(brainpos),1,white), (250, 570))
    screen.blit(datafont.render("column1.y: "+
str(column1.y+800),1,white), (500, 570))
    screen.blit(datafont.render("difficulty: "+
str(difficulty),1,white), (650, 570))

    display.update()

# print playerbrain.y

# collision dection
    if ((playerbrain.y < column1.y+801 or playerbrain.y >
column2.y-74) and (x <150 and x > 20)):
        mixer.music.stop()
        mixer.Sound.play(crasheffect)
        print "BUMP"
        gameover = 1

# check if clicked x on window to exit
    for ourevent in event.get():
        if ourevent.type == QUIT:
            quit = 1

# has key been pressed. K_q is to quit
        if ourevent.type == KEYDOWN:
            if ourevent.key == K_DOWN:
                playerbrain.y = playerbrain.y+10

            if ourevent.key == K_UP:
                playerbrain.y = playerbrain.y-10

            if ourevent.key == K_q:
                quit = 1

# if game over show message
while gameover == 1 and quit == 0:
    screen.blit(overfont.render("GAME OVER",1,yellow), (380, 260))
    display.update()

# then wait for a key to pressed  before starting again
    for ourevent in event.get():
        if ourevent.type == KEYDOWN:
            if ourevent.key == K_0:
                difficulty = 0
                score = 0
                gameover = 0
                mixer.music.play(-1)

            if ourevent.key == K_1:
                difficulty = 1
                score = 0
                gameover = 0
                mixer.music.play(-1)

            if ourevent.key == K_2:
                difficulty = 2
                score = 0
                gameover = 0
                mixer.music.play(-1)

            if ourevent.key == K_SPACE:
                score = 0
                gameover = 0
                mixer.music.play(-1)

            if ourevent.key == K_q:
                quit = 1
                score = 0
                gameover = 0
```

I execute this script on the `Raspery Pi` by a `sudo python flappybrain.py` command. Of course, I make sure everything is hooked up properly. When I run the `Arduino` `IDE` I can see good output from the `EEG`.

However, when I execute the script, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flappybrain.py", line 125, in <module>
    signal,att,med,delta,theta,lalpha,halpha,lbeta,hbeta,lgamma,hgamma
= data.split(",")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I don't get this error when the `MindFlex` isn't hooked up (it just hangs, then). Having looked at the raw output from `MindFlex`, it comes as lines of numbers; the values from the `EEG`. Clearly, the script is having trouble with that. A typical line might look like:

```
20010,2140,43234,345,2342,2342,4534,5643,564,3244,7865
```

I can see what the script is trying to do, just not why it can't do it. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have come across a line of input that contains none of these delimiters (commas).  You can handle `ValueError` (on this line only!) by `continue` or put a guard that checks for comma and does `continue`.  Or you can filter out lines which don't contain commas, if that makes sense.

Otherwise you must reject this input if it's invalid.

For example:

```
    data = ser.readline()
# print data
    EXPECTED_FIELD_COUNT = 11 
    if len(data.split(',')) != EXPECTED_FIELD_COUNT:
        continue 
    signal,att,med,delta,theta,lalpha,halpha,lbeta,hbeta,lgamma,hgamma = data.split(",")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm a novice, could you maybe help with the code "fix"? I'm a teacher working with my kids to get this working. I'll work on it to try and learn, too.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up to say thank you! This made the code work like a charm. It's a bit funny to watch my students controlling a Flappy Brain game with just their minds! Would not have happened without your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Go ahead and accept this answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

make sure if `type(data)` is `<type 'str'>`, if not you should:

```
str(data).split(",")
```

and if you need and int type:

```
int(result[i])
```